# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm currently trying to create an address book GUI for a school project. At the moment I am attempting to link my validation to the GUI, but keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\katie_000\Downloads\GUI adresses practice (1).py", line 198,  in <module>
B = Button(window, width=46, text = "Add",fg="gray16", command=name())
File "C:\Users\katie_000\Downloads\GUI adresses practice (1).py", line 8, in name
Sname()
File "C:\Users\katie_000\Downloads\GUI adresses practice (1).py", line 17, in Sname
Hphone()
File "C:\Users\katie_000\Downloads\GUI adresses practice (1).py", line 24, in Hphone
label.configure("You must enter a phone number")
File "C:\Users\katie_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36  \lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1479, in configure
return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Users\katie_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36  \lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1469, in _configure
return self._getconfigure1(_flatten((self._w, cmd, '-'+cnf)))
File "C:\Users\katie_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1457, in _getconfigure1
x = self.tk.splitlist(self.tk.call(*args))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-You must enter a phone number"
```

It would be great if someone could tell me what this means, as I can't find any information that helps me.

Many Thanks

Comment: You'd have to show relevant code as well, not only the traceback.

Comment: However, from the traceback, I can tell you that you don't configure a label like that - if you want to set its text, you need to specify the parameter like so. `label.configure(text='You must ... ')`. You also do not need parenthesis in `command=name()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `label.configure("You must enter a phone number")` will try and assign `label` with an attribute of `"You must enter a phone number"` which isn't an attribute that `Label` widgets have. If you're trying to set the text value of the widget (as was pointed out by mentalita above) you need to assigned the value to the `text` attribute like so `label.configure(text="You must enter a phone number")`.